# Using String#contains() and String#indexOf() to locate a date format String in a comma separated list finds incorrect matches

Tags: java, string

I want to check whether the date format `dd/MM/yy` is present in the following list of formats:

```
String validDateFormats = "dd/MM/yyyy,dd-MM-yyyy,MM/dd/yyyy,MM-dd-yyyy";
```

The following returns `true`, even though I expected `false` (since the list doesn't contain the format `dd/MM/yy`):

```
System.out.println(validDateFormats.contains("dd/MM/yy"));
```

The following returns `0` event though I expected `-1` (since the list doesn't contain the format `dd/MM/yy`):

```
System.out.println(validDateFormats.indexOf("dd/MM/yy"));
```

How can I get the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: Why do you expect false and -1?

Comment: It looks like what you want is to split on commas then look for an item in an array.

Comment: how do you expect false for the first one? if the result is positive, return false? they work just fine, but I think you don't understand what they do

Comment: Thats how both `String.Contains` and `String.IndexOf` works. You should be using regex for your requirement. Or store all the valid formats in an array and then search the array to validate the supplied date format!

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy` contains `dd/MM/yy` at index 0 so the methods work as intended. Use one of the solutions the others already suggested.

Comment: If you store the values in a `String[]` array. You could sort the array `Arrays.sort(validDateFormats)` and then do a binary search `Arrays.binarySearch(validDateFormats, "dd/mm/yy")` to check if the pattern is included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you are not searching for a single date format in a list of date formats, you are searching for a date format `String` within a single `String` that contains multiple comma separated date formats.

Since that `String` starts with `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, which contains `"dd/MM/yy"`, both `contains` and `indexOf` find a match (which, given your requirements, is a false positive).

In order to search for full date formats only (in your comma separated list), you should split your input `String` into a `List<String>`, and run contains of that `List`:

```
Arrays.asList(validDateFormats.split(",")).contains("dd/MM/yy")
```

`validDateFormats.split(",")` splits the input `String` into a String array (using the comma as a separator). `Arrays.asList` creates a `List<String>` backed by that array, which allows you to run `List`'s `contains` method to search for the `"dd/MM/yy"` date format. This will return `false` as expected.

Comment: Alternative - add `','` to beginning and end, and then check for `contains(",dd/MM/yy,")`.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work, in the following case it fails                                                                                                 String validDateFormats = "dd/MM/yyyy,dd-MM-yyyy,MM/dd/yyyy,MM-dd-yyyy";
System.out.println(validDateFormats.contains(",dd/MM/yyyy,"));

Comment: @sskini Can you be more specific? (show input, output and code that doesn't work)

Comment: Arrays.asList(validDateFormats.split(",")).contains("dd/MM/yy")                    this on works, thanks Eran

Comment: One last question, what if there is no delimiter (,) ? Then how do we check ?

Comment: @sskini If there is no delimiter, how do you determine where one date format ends and the next date format begins?